# a Looped OnClickListener always gets the wrong index array

Tags: android

I have this loop method to display a `ViewPager` and I set an `OnClickListener` for each Image on the `ViewPager`. So when the image is clicked, the user will be brought to a VideoPlayer class. but I don't know why, the `footage_video_url[i]` on `putExtra()` of the click listener always reads that the `i` on the extra is the maximum length. So the `i` always exceeds the maximum array length and that makes the app crash.

What I was expecting is, if for example the displayed image is `footage_thumbnail_url[1]`, the String which is put on extra is `footage_video_url[1]` respectively, and so on.
Does anybody know where I go wrong?

```
for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
                final String[] video_url = footage_video_url;
                final String[] thumbnail_url = footage_thumbnail_url;

                //System.out.println("FOOTAGE VIDEO DETAILS " +i+ ": " +video_url[i]);

                FrameLayout content = new FrameLayout(this);
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        (int) size, (int) size);
                params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader(this);

                // Image from URL
                if (footage_thumbnail_url[i].contains("http"))
                    loader.downloadPicture(imageView, footage_thumbnail_url,i);
                else {
                    // Image From SDCard
                    File imgFile = new File(thumbnail_url[i]);
                    Bitmap bitmapImage = loader.decodeFile(imgFile);
                    Drawable drawableImage = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapImage);
                    imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawableImage);

                    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent listIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    VideoPlayer.class);
                            listIntent.putExtra("video_url", footage_video_url[i]);
                            System.out.println("Video Number "+i+" : "+ footage_video_url[i]);
                            startActivity(listIntent);
                        }
                    });
                }


                content.addView(imageView);

                View overlay = new View(this);
                overlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                overlay.setLayoutParams(params);
                overlay.invalidate();

                content.addView(overlay);
                pagerViews.add(content);



            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set as the tag for the `ImageView` the string `footage_video_url[i]` and then retrieve it in the `OnClickListener`. This way you're sure the correct String will be put in the extras:

```
imageView.setTag(footage_video_url[i]);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
          String theUrl = (String) v.getTag(); // I hope it's a String
          Intent listIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    VideoPlayer.class);
          listIntent.putExtra("video_url", theUrl);
          System.out.println("Video Number "+i+" : "+ theUrl);
          startActivity(listIntent);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take imageView as an array of length n. Then before your for loop, add 1 more for loop where u'll set the tags for all the 'n' imageViews, something like this:

```
for(int x=0;x<length;x++)
     imageView[x].setTag(x);
```

then inside your loop replace these lines:

```
listIntent.putExtra("video_url", footage_video_url[i]);
System.out.println("Video Number "+i+" : "+ footage_video_url[i]);
```

with these lines:

```
listIntent.putExtra("video_url", footage_video_url[imageView[i].getTag(i)]);
System.out.println("Video Number "+i+" : "+ footage_video_url[imageView[i].getTag(i)]);
```

Hope this might help !!